# How to get variable value from template?

Tags: angular

I have a async data:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let application of (applicationService.applications | async)?.items" [ngTemplateOutlet]="ordersTableBodyTemplate"
[ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ application: application, index: index }">
</ng-container>

<ng-template let-application="application" let-i="index" #ordersTableBodyTemplate>
    <input #checkboxes type="checkbox" (click)="selectCheckbox($event)" />
</ng-template>
```

There is method that checkes all checkboxes on the page inside `#ordersTableBodyTemplate`:

```
@ViewChildren('checkboxes') checkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

So, when I get queryList and convert it to array I neeed to get `application` value for each item:

```
this.checkboxes.toArray().filter((element) => element.nativeElement.checked).map((element) => {
    return application variable;
});
```

Sure I can pass application variable in click: `(click)="selectCheckbox(application)"` but I dont like it.

Comment: Please explain more in detail what your problem is, possibly with a reproducer to being able to help you out better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method won't have any context about where it was placed in the template.  You can pass it like a parameter as you are doing, or you can create a new component instead of using ng-template.

Something like this

```js
@Component({
selector: 'app-checkbox-component'
})
export class AppCheckboxComponent {
@Input() application: Application;

selectCheckbox() {
 // do something here, but now you can call this.application to get the application
}
}
```

And your parent component template can be changed to call that instead of an ng-template

```html
<app-checkbox-component *ngFor="let application of (applicationService.applications | async)?.items" [application]="application">
</app-checkbox-component>
```

Comment: Then to use `@ViewChildren` to get selected checkboxes?

Comment: And to store statement of checkbox in component?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the `input`s doesn't have any context of the `application` variable. One way would be to bind the value using `data` attribute and retrieve it in the controller.

Try the following

```html
<ng-template let-application="application" let-i="index" #ordersTableBodyTemplate>
  <input #checkboxes type="checkbox" [attr.data-application]="application" (click)="selectCheckbox($event)" />
</ng-template>
```

Notice the `[attr.data-application]="application"` binding. Here the `application` is bound to a data attribute called `application`. Now we could retrieve from the event in the controller

```js
this.checkboxes.toArray().filter((element) => element.nativeElement.checked).map((element) => {
  return event.target.dataset.application;
});
```